# Use of unresolved identifier ParseCrashReporting

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, parse-platform

I am using Parse in my app and everything works well except ParseCrashReporting. I get the error :

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'ParseCrashReporting'
```

When I do in Swift :

```
ParseCrashReporting.enable()
```

What should I do ?

Comment: Have you imported `<Parse/Parse.h>` in your Bridge Header?

Comment: It's there. I am already using PFObjects. Everything is OK with Parse in my app. The only problem comes from ParseCrashReporting.

Comment: are you maybe including an old version of the parse framework, or some old headers still lingering around? the crash reporting feature has been introduced in the end of last year

Comment: I started using Parse in March this year with the latest SDK at that moment...

Comment: out of curiosity does your parse framework have the PFLogInViewController and SignUp? are you using them? cause I'm facing the same issue where I downloaded the latest version of Parse containing these views however I have some headers missing, like the PFConfig and ParseCrashReporting. And the latest SDK has the login and signup missing... Not sure what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have the correct frameworks - you will need to import, **ParseCrashReporting.framework** (found in the Parse SDK download), and **libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib**; once you have these, make sure you import the frameworks from your `AppDelegate`:

```
import Parse
import ParseCrashReporting
import Bolts
```

[image]

Remember that **all Parse frameworks needs to be at the same version** - if you just recently added `ParseCrashReporting` make sure that it matches the version number of your previous Parse SDK.

Comment: I just downloaded the latest Parse SDK but it does not have ```ParseCrashReporting framework.```